# Is there a limit on number of MS Graph API calls?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an App in Azure and given, as I thought, sufficient privileges.
Now when using the Api from the App, I get occasional errors.

For example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/members?$select=id,userPrincipalName
```

gives usually the correct result, i.e. the members of the group. When I run it multiple times, however, I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2020-04-27T07:35:43"
    }
  }
}
```

This happens not only from the app, but using Postman with the same credentials.
How can I have insufficient privileges, if the call has gone through multiple times already, then all of a sudden it does not.

Is there a limit on number of MS Graph API calls? I couldn't find any informatin on this.
Appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everyone trying to help here. But the problem apparently was with Microsoft.
After seeing a couple of other people having the same problem, I put it aside for a few days.
Now revisiting my app, all the calls work fine.

Comment: as i know there is no limit. you can paste your access token to  jwt.ms website and see which privileges your access token has

Comment: The privileges are there for groups and group members, etc.
When I run it via Postman I get the correct response, on average every 5th request is denied, though.

Comment: MS Graph has limits(Reference:[Throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling)). In your case it is not due to limit.It is due to postman.Use Graph explorer instead

Comment: It actually happens within the Application. I was just using Postman to evaluate my calls and the responses without everything else around it. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Ms Graph level permissions for fixing the error. According to
[List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) documentation One of the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) permissions is required to call this API. To Use Graph API in Postman find document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman).

To learn more, including how to choose permissions, See [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).